# language change my laptop windows 8

Tags: windows-8, language, regional-settings

I have an HP laptop computer running Windows 8. It was purchased in the NORWAY and is in NORWEGIAN. I need to  use English  and have the entire system language be English. Can I change this myself or do I need to purchase Windows 8 in English and install that on the laptop?

Comment: You don't need to purchase an english version. You can change it using language settings
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9780735670952/4dot-customizing-windows-8/id679819

Comment: @Khaleel you should post this as answer.

Comment: @Khaleel I encourage you to type in your comment as *asnwer*, you'll just get the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

No need to purchase any new version. 
Just go to the language settings in control panel, there you will find an option to download language packs. Download English language pack, It is free and should take only a few minutes.

Now set out as your default language.

Answer (score 1):

You can always change the language display settings,for the whole interface and also change the keyboard layout settings (maybe this last might be a lil complicated but it can be fully solved too).

So, for changing display language, you must download some ***language packs***, avaliable for a plenty ammount of languages.These you can get them from here:

[**Microsoft Windows site for language packs downloading.**](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win8)

And instructions are avaliable here:

[**Windows 8 language customization.**](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/language)

In resumed words, all you have to do is:

1. Going  to the first web site,
2. find and download the US English language pack,
3. then go to Control Panel, Clock, Language and Region settings,
4. go exactly for Language settings
5. and in Add Language option, load the previously downloaded language
   pack.

I think you can even download the pack at the moment once you get to step 5.